# facebook login js sdk redirect

Tags: facebook, authentication

am trying to use facebook login on my site and here is how i load the sdk

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
   appId      : '362869753746986', // App ID
   channelUrl : '//WWW.FESTIVEHUB.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
   cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
 });

// Additional initialization code here
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

and the login button

```
 <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="2"></div>
```

if i click the login button it shows a new facebook window for login and if i do it logs in the problem however are after the login the small new window remains and it blank but if i manually close it and refresh my page the login button is replaced with my FB profile picture so i need that login window to close automatically and i need a callback function so i can take action after the login. NB am working on localhost if its worth noting!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK, but your issue is probably your channelUrl file. The domain on the channel URL, your applications registered URL, and the URL you are trying to login from all have to match. The channel file also needs to have a single line

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

to work.